# How to make a wrapper for the figure and table environments.

Tags: floats, environments

I am familiar with the `newenvironment` command, but I was wondering, how do I carry on the parameters that are used between `[ ]`, i.e `[bht!]`?

I want to make a `newfig` and a `newtab` environment that will take care of some stuff that I don't want to redo everytime, i.e. center a figure or set text size to small.. I am lazy, and this can improve the readability of my tex document as well.

I know I can define them as normal parameters like this :

```
\newenvironment{tableC}[2]
{\begin{table}[#1#2]\begin{center}}
{\end{center}\end{table}}
```

but these parameters are not always present, and do not necessarily have a default value. For example, the ! parameter has no default equivalent (or does it?). What can I do from this point?

EDIT: Using floats, I was able to do what I needed. Here is how I did it for tables :

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{tableC}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{tableC}{Table}
\floatevery{tableC}{\centering}
```

Comment: Not particularly related, but R has a nice feature, where you can put "..." in the list of arguments a function takes, and then within the function use "..." to pass that list of arguments to other functions within it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the float package

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatevery{figure}{\centering}
\floatplacement{figure}{bht}
```

It also provides a `\newfloat` command.

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if you simply define a new environment with an optional argument and a sensible default?

```
\newenvironment{newtable}[1][hbt]{\table[#1]\centering}{\endtable}
```

Then you can write

```
\begin{newtable}
... stuff ...
\end{newtable}

\begin{newtable}[hbt!]
... stuff ...
\end{newtable}

\begin{newtable}[H]
... stuff ...
\end{newtable}
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. I remember trying to do this and not being able to, must have messed up somewhere :D

Comment: To be fair, I also misread your question the first time you posted it, and I was going to suggest some wild TeX-ish hack. Luckily, the problem was actually quite simple!