# How do I make custom float environments use the same numbering for captions.

Tags: floats, captions, numbering

I use a custom float environment that is basically used as a table environment that provides extra formatting. I would like this environment to use the same numbering as the regular table floats. Is there a way to do that? I have already changed the floatname to match Table by using the floatname command. Here is my initialization code:

```
\newfloat{newtable}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{newtable}{Table}
```

Regular tables numbering also span over chapters... do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this only to get a second table environment with different formatting, why don't you simply define it in terms of the existing `table`? For example something like

```
\newenvironment{newtable}{\table[opts]\formatting\stuff}{\endtable}
```

Comment: Or if the OP must use a new float for whatever reason, another option is to define a wrapper environment `newnewtable` which in its initialization `\setcounter{newtable}{table}` before loading `newtable`, and in its end `\setcounter{table}{newtable}` after ending `newtable`.

Comment: I kind of need the float functionalities [hbt]... I asked in a previous question how to pass on the [opts] in a new environment and the solution which I got was to use floats... With what you are proposing I would be stuck with the same problem/question...

Comment: I see, I've just posted a [new answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/how-to-make-a-wrapper-for-the-figure-and-table-environments/4080#4080) there.

Answer (score 1):

A hackish solution - possibly with adverse effects - is to increment the `table` counter after a `newtable` environment and vice versa.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{newtable}{tbp}{lop}[chapter]
\floatname{newtable}{Table}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\endnewtable{\refstepcounter{table}}
\g@addto@macro\endtable{\refstepcounter{newtable}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{newtable}[!ht]
\caption{A newtable}
\end{newtable}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```